# Eclipse, C++ and Mysql

Tags: c++, mysql, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, ubuntu-12.04

I am reading the follow article [Developing MySQL Applications with Eclipse CDT](http://ftp.nchu.edu.tw/MySQL/tech-resources/articles/mysql-capi-tutorial.html). My Eclipse version is **Indigo** and my **Ubuntu** version is 12.04. When I trying build I get the following errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz.a
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmysqlclient.a
```

I like please get help. I searched `mysqlclient.a` and `z.a` libraries but not found these. But I found `libmysqlclient.a` and `libz.a` in directory `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` then I add this Library search path but get the error.

How I will be able to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You passed `z.a` and `mysqlclient.a` as libraries. You need to ditch the `.a` suffix in your project's build settings: it's not part of the library's name. It should be `-lz` and `-lmysqlclient`.

Also, adding the library search path (`-L`) is probably not necessary. `/usr/lib` and `/usr/lib/$arch$` are usually in the default search paths.

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the MySQL client library and the libz compression library. Do an 'apt-cache search' for either.

This question is probably better suited for serverfault.com.

Comment: I installed these libraries, but I get the same error. I found the libraries libmysqlclient.a and libz.a in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu directory but equal I get the same error

Comment: It's definitely not best suited for serverfault.com. It's perfectly fine to ask questions like these here.